# Push Buttons in Tkinter and Matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I would like to generate a Matplotlib plot in Tkinter via a button push. The button is supposed to start a data collection routine (ultimately from the serial port) and data are to be plotted when the collection process is finished. The code below is simplified and just contains some dummy data. My problem is that no graph appears when pushing the "plot" button.

```
import tkinter
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

window = tkinter.Tk()

fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window) 
canvas.draw()

def plotData(ax):
    xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    ys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)
   
CloseButton = tkinter.Button(master=window, text="Close", command=window.destroy)
PlotButton = tkinter.Button(master=window, text = "Plot", command = lambda: plotData(ax))
    
CloseButton.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx = 10, pady = 10)
PlotButton.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT, padx = 10, pady = 10)

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `canvas.draw()` to the end of the function.

```
def plotData(ax):
    xs = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    ys = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    ax.clear()
    ax.plot(xs, ys)
    canvas.draw()
```

Comment: With this help, I also realized that the lambda function and passing ax as an argument are not required for making this work.